# Проблема с разметкой xml. Появляется непонятная белая полоска

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

[image]

Подскажите что с этим делать.

Разметка Activity:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title="@string/app_name">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerNest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Разметка fragment:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_3" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Смена CoordinatorLayout на другой не помогает?

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` в разметке фрагмента

Comment: убрал android:fitsSystemWindows="true" - белая полоска пропала

Comment: @ermak0ff сделайте ваш комментарий как ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта полоса представляет собой отступ и равняется высоте статус бара. Отвечает за это следующая строка:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

в разметке фрагмента.

Решение - удалить данную строчку из разметки фрагмента.